# Use unmanaged(C) buffer in managed code(C#) in .NET Compact Framework

Tags: c#, .net, c, windows, windows-ce

I have two functions.

1. To register a call back function which is defined in C.
2. The call back function in C#, which consists of a IntPtr buffer.

In C, I create a byte buffer and update the IntPtr with the call back function.

The problem is that, I could not able to print the buffer in C# label object. But I am able to show this in the MessageBox.

C# functions:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Tempclass.RegCallback(Callback);
}



 public void Callback(IntPtr data,ref  int size)
    {
    byte[] ReadData = new byte[size];

    Marshal.Copy(data, ReadData, 0, size); 

    String szData  = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, size); 
    label1.Text =   szData; // error is here.    
    }
```

C functions:

```
typedef void (__stdcall * Callback)( _Out_ byte* , _Out_ int*);
void RM2RegImgCallback (_In_ Callback pfnCallback)
{
    char    buffer[4]={0x64,0x65,0x66,0x00};
    DWORD size =4;
    pfnCallback((byte*)buffer,(int*)&size);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should post your code, then. Otherwise, how should anybody know what you did wrong?

Comment: Please show the unmanaged code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't complete.  What does `Tempclass.Regcallback` look like?  You should be calling `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` at some point and the result of that call is what should be going across the P/Invoke boundary.

Answer (score -1):

Check that the .net Framework is working with wide chars, so maybe you should work in wide chars in C.